# Prevent iOS safari from moving web-page window so drag event can happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, multi-touch

I am using Pep.js for kinetic drag on multi-touch, but my drag events are not being registered because when I try to drag an object in the safari, on iOS, window the window itself moves and follows my drag.

How can I prevent the browser window from following my drag so that the `<div>` in my webpage can be dragged?

Here is the webpage in question: http://goo.gl/TsHgh. Click on the link and a `<div>` slides in, it is that div that is draggable. It works on desktop browsers, but can not be dragged on multi-touch because safari moves the window along with my drag.

Answer (score 38):

I have found this solution while working with the [#ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com/)

CSS:

```
html, body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).bind(
  'touchmove',
   function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
);
```

Comment: if we apply just overflow rule it will not allow scrolling the page down. I think it should be overflow-x

Comment: Caution -- if you do overflow hidden on either x or y on the body, it will prevent the minimal url bar effect on mobile safari, where you drag up and the URL bar disappears. Also, the touchmove bind doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is what is causing the issue.

Well, the class your animation is being applied to.

Remove the class after the animation is done.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#tabViewWindow').removeClass('animated').removeClass('bounceInRight');
}, 1200);
```

Also, to disable scrolling on the window:

```
html, body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply globaly to

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the other answers from 2013-2014?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

To head tag in your html

Comment: that just disables zooming. I understand it is good practice to have that, but how will that prevent the window from moving?