# (Angular 4) How to a Bind Global Touch Event Handler to Disable iOS Safari Page Drag?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, mobile-safari

The practical problem here is that I have an Angular 4 app that has a D3.js chart that takes input via user touch drag (bound with 'touchstart'). The user drags a needle to a value, which is registered upon touch end (bound with 'touchend').

However on a mobile browser, at least on iOS Safari, when I touch and start dragging the whole window starts to move...like dragging to right starts to show the last visited page.

I will be trying out this as a fix: [Prevent iOS safari from moving web-page window so drag event can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068026/prevent-ios-safari-from-moving-web-page-window-so-drag-event-can-happen)

But I will need to register a global event handler in Angular 4 – how to achieve this, or any better suggestions for the problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763141/is-there-any-lifecycle-hook-like-window-onbeforeunload-in-angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem! Add this to head in index.html or define elsewhere in your JS scripts:

```
<script>
  document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what your real problem is ..

If you're talking about Safari history gestures (swipe starting off-screen to the right shows the last visited page), then it seems that it's handled on OS/browser level and we don't have any callback, check comments here :
[iOS 7 - is there a way to disable the swipe back and forward functionality in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889666/ios-7-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-swipe-back-and-forward-functionality-in-sa)

Comment: The real problem is that I've built an mobile application that has a gauge chart element. It has a needle pointer which user can drag (touchstart / touchmove / touchend events)... But on iOS Safari horizontal dragging drags the whole page because of this history gesture.